# Is it possible to flag/mark/label a specific SVN revision as tested?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to flag/mark/label a specific SVN revision as `tested` (or any other label for that matter)?

There are several use cases of this feature:

1. As a non-dev user of SVN (for example, manager), it would be useful to be able to differentiate and get only the revisions that were `tested` and `flagged as working`.
2. In case the revision was flagged as, for example, `Eligible for release`, the release could be made automatically.
3. One can filter out specific labels in order to see only those which were:

   - released,
   - not tested,
   - had crashes,
   - so on.

So I'd be surprised if it's not implemented already, but Googling didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

- Branch|tag any and every revision (commitable  tags are against common convention, but it's possible anyway/), just follow some coherent and accepted in team policies
- Use [custom revision properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.ref.unversioned) (see second forms of `svn ps`|`svn pg`|`svn pl`)

I, personally, will prefer tagging - it's faster and, in common, more easier way, than property-manipulation

Comment: [Branch|Tag creates a folder isolated from the main line of development](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html), right? If so, it's not what I had in mind. I need something like: (1) commit change = rev 123, (2) test change, (3) flag revision 123 as tested - with no other folders involved.

Comment: And, related to custom revision properties - it looks like those properties are reserved for Subversion's own use - I don't see how I can control what properties a revision has and what values it holds.

Comment: I see yet another upvote. Is it just me who thinks this doesn't answer my question? If so, can someone clarify how this helps me achieve what I asked for?

Comment: @Adelin - yes, I'll expand my answer for you with details and samples

Comment: Thanks - no rush. I'm new to SVN, so it could be that I don't understand properly how branch|tag works